# Scroll not applied when height of the window decreases

Tags: html, css, material-ui, frontend

Im trying to build a Responsive Modal and cant adjust the height of the modal when the window height decreases.
The content slips under the window and the scroll bar is also not adjusted to the window height.
I have a nested div structure which kind of messing up everything.
[image]

**The content is still of the same height and wraps under :(**

[image]
Codesandbox link-
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sara-kpk9c?file=/src/Components/Modal.css

Stuck on this since very long...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey. To handle this case you need to listen to `resize` event on window.

Comment: its because modal will remove the scroll property on open,you need to remove it if you want but usually screens wont go this small in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the max-height: 100vh; to the .ModalSection2 class.
Here is the working example :https://codesandbox.io/s/async-monad-xie2p?file=/src/Components/Modal.css:1653-1666

Comment: Awesome! But .ModalSection1 will also require the same i guess